# Disabling a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

net MVC & jquery I need to disable a link incase no text is entered in the text box. Can someone please help me as to how to do it?

Comment: You should show us example of code where you want to do this.

Comment: I have not written the code for this.I am new to asp.net MVC so i do not have much idea about how to implement this.

Comment: Damn Kiril you fast ...

Comment: It's simple just put your HTML code

Comment: you mean the view code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#linkId").click(function(){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  if($("#textFieldId").val().length !== 0){
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
  }
});
```